# The partial derivatives of $ log(x/y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would just like to check if this partial derivatives are right. I am using the chain rule. It's just that it still confuses me a bit, differentiating in two variables.

If $f(x,y) = log(x/y)$, then

${\delta f \over \delta x} = {1 \over {x \over y}} ({1 \over y}) = {y \over x} {1 \over y} = {1 \over x}$

${\delta f \over \delta y} = {1 \over {x \over y}} ({-x \over y^2}) = {y \over x} {-x \over y^2} = {-1 \over y}$

Comment: Why don't you write $\log(x/y)=\log(x)-\log(y)$ ? You have a sign error for the second.

Comment: ah yes! thanks! -----------------------